# Issues with loading Multiple Application files in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm just started working on Spring Boot and having issues while running the spring boot application. SO scenario is -  i have two project

One is called Parent Project SpringBoot and

Other project called web-app is maven module which added in Parent project as module.

In Both Projects(Parent and child) i have Application classes which load the context but somehow when i start the application it gives me some exceptions like on project **SpringBoot: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a mainClass property**

On top of that when i run the web-app separately then it works but when i run it through Parent Project SpringBoot it throws me exceptions

Here is my code structure of  Spring Boot Project (Parent Project)

**`Application.java`**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Example.java**

```
@RequestMapping("/api/**")
@RestController
public class Example {@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public String index() {
return "Hello World";
}


}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBoot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- Additional lines to be added here... -->


    <modules>
        <module>web-app</module>
    </modules
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Second project which is web-app:**

**ApplicationWebApp.Java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@SpringBootApplication
ApplicationWebApp
public class ApplicationWebApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationWebApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Example.java**

```
@RequestMapping("/apis/**")
@RestController
public class Example {@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =           {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public String index() {
return "Hello World";
}
}
```

**Pom.xml**

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>SpringBoot</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </parent>
      <artifactId>web-app</artifactId>
    </project>
```

I found couple of solutions on the stackoverflow and different forums by adding

```
      <properties>
                The main class to start by executing java -jar
<startclass>com.dashboard.backend.controllers.Application</startclass>
            </properties>
```

By this way, i need to add this properly file in each n every pom.xml to load it. Since this is a web based application so I'm not sure whether its a good solution or not..

If anyone have tried any solution for this problem please share you findings

Comment: So are you trying to launch them all from a parent project? Or is the parent project itself supposed to be a web application?

Comment: yes i want to launch it from a parent project. All projects(Parent and Child) are web project